# Can we get a way to view all our questions across the network?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

I am currently reviewing my questions to see if there are any answers that should be accepted, any outdated things that could be revised etc. But there does not seem to be a good way to do it for all sites combined.

The network profile lacks basic information, for example if there is an accepted answer to a question. The profiles on the subsites work well, but only show the content of the subsite. I would like to have a "combined" profile that shows all questions and answers together in a combined profile view. The network profile currently does not achieve that. For my purposes, formatting it like the other profiles (with green vote count showing questions with accepted answers) would already help.

Comment: On the network profile, you can go to the "top" tab, but that will only show posts with a score of 5 or more. You can also go to activity > posts, but that won't show their score of if they have an accepted answer.